# Toggle Check/Uncheck checkboxes when child or parent is selected?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, telerik

This code below is from the Telerik Treeview control. I need to be able to Toggle a child when a child is selected and unselected. I need to be able to toggle all children when the parent is selected and unselected.

```
   <% Html.Telerik().TreeView()
                           .Name("MultiLocationPicker")
                           .ClientEvents(events1 => events1.OnSelect("MultiLocationPicker_Selected"))
                           .ClientEvents(events => events
                                .OnChecked("MultiLocationPicker_Checked")
                            )
                           .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "position:absolute;padding-top:5px;background-color:#EAEAEA;color:#3F8AC4;z-index:2000;display:none" })
                           .ShowCheckBox(true)
                           .BindTo(getAvailableLocations, mappings =>
                        {
                            mappings.For<RegionEntity>(binding => binding
                                .ItemDataBound((item, region) =>
                                                   {
                                                       item.Text = region.RecordName;
                                                       item.Value = ""; 
                                                       var regionNode = regionNodes.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Equals(region.RecordName));
                                                       var le = new List<LocationEntity>(region.Location);
                                                       bool isChecked = false;
                                                       foreach (var l in le)
                                                       {
                                                           if (userLocations.Contains(l.ID))
                                                           {
                                                               isChecked = true;
                                                           }
                                                           else
                                                           {
                                                               isChecked = false;
                                                               break;
                                                           }
                                                       }

                                                       item.Checked = isChecked;
                                                       item.Expanded = true;

                                                   }).Children(location => location.Location));
                            mappings.For<LocationEntity>(binding => binding
                                                                        .ItemDataBound((item, location) =>
                                                                                          {
                                                                                              item.Text = location.Name;
                                                                                              item.Value =
                                                                                                  location.ID.ToString();
                                                                                              item.Checked = userLocations.Contains(location.ID);

                                                                                          }

                                                                                           ));

                        }).Render();%>  

    </li> 
    <input type="hidden" id="isDirty" value="false"/>
    <%
      }
     %>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[

        var allVals = [];
        $('#spnloc').hover(function () {
            $('#MultiLocationPicker').show();
        });
        $('#MultiLocationPicker').mouseenter(function () {
            $('#MultiLocationPicker').show();

        });

        function MultiLocationPicker_Selected(e) {

            var item = $(e.item);
            var checkbox = item.find('.t-checkbox:first [type=checkbox]');                

            !checkbox.is(':checked') ? checkbox.attr('checked', 'checked') : checkbox.removeAttr('checked');                                      


        }                                                   


HTML Markup for the above control given below:                                                  


  <div style=
  "position: absolute; padding-top: 5px; background-color: rgb(234, 234, 234); color: rgb(63, 138, 196); z-index: 2000;"
  id="MultiLocationPicker" class="t-widget t-treeview t-reset">
    <ul class="t-group t-treeview-lines">
      <li class="t-item t-first">
        <div class="t-top">
          <span class="t-checkbox"><input type="hidden" value="0" name=
          "MultiLocationPicker_checkedNodes.Index" class="t-input" /><input type=
          "checkbox" value="False" name="MultiLocationPicker_checkedNodes[0].Checked"
          class="t-input" /></span><span class="t-in">Main Region</span><input type=
          "hidden" value="Main Region" name="itemValue" class="t-input" />
        </div>

        <ul class="t-group">
          <li class="t-item">
            <div class="t-top">
              <span class="t-checkbox"><input type="hidden" value="0:0" name=
              "MultiLocationPicker_checkedNodes.Index" class="t-input" /><input type=
              "checkbox" value="False" name=
              "MultiLocationPicker_checkedNodes[0:0].Checked" class=
              "t-input" /></span><span class="t-in">North Vancouver</span><input type=
              "hidden" value="5761a893-9ef0-48d3-847a-2638ec081f5f" name="itemValue"
              class="t-input" />
            </div>
          </li>

          <li class="t-item">
            <div class="t-mid">
              <span class="t-checkbox"><input type="hidden" value="0:1" name=
              "MultiLocationPicker_checkedNodes.Index" class="t-input" /><input type=
              "checkbox" value="False" name=
              "MultiLocationPicker_checkedNodes[0:1].Checked" class=
              "t-input" /></span><span class="t-in">testLocation2</span><input type=
              "hidden" value="d63d6ff6-07dc-4021-a4bb-7b1b7c781119" name="itemValue"
              class="t-input" />
            </div>
          </li>

          <li class="t-item t-last">
            <div class="t-bot">
              <span class="t-checkbox"><input type="hidden" value="0:2" name=
              "MultiLocationPicker_checkedNodes.Index" class="t-input" /><input type=
              "checkbox" value="False" name=
              "MultiLocationPicker_checkedNodes[0:2].Checked" class=
              "t-input" /></span><span class="t-in">TestLocations123</span><input type=
              "hidden" value="eadfd0f5-9181-4094-b01a-9d7ee383b7f2" name="itemValue"
              class="t-input" />
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li class="t-item">
        <div class="t-mid">
          <span class="t-checkbox"><input type="hidden" value="1" name=
          "MultiLocationPicker_checkedNodes.Index" class="t-input" /><input type=
          "checkbox" value="False" name="MultiLocationPicker_checkedNodes[1].Checked"
          class="t-input" /></span><span class="t-in">World</span><input type="hidden"
          value="World" name="itemValue" class="t-input" />
        </div>

        <ul class="t-group">
          <li class="t-item">
            <div class="t-top">
              <span class="t-checkbox"><input type="hidden" value="1:0" name=
              "MultiLocationPicker_checkedNodes.Index" class="t-input" /><input type=
              "checkbox" value="False" name=
              "MultiLocationPicker_checkedNodes[1:0].Checked" class=
              "t-input" /></span><span class="t-in">Sydney GMT+10</span><input type=
              "hidden" value="ca1033d4-a9ca-4e16-96ea-3b92ab6e1c52" name="itemValue"
              class="t-input" />
            </div>
          </li>

          <li class="t-item t-last">
            <div class="t-bot">
              <span class="t-checkbox"><input type="hidden" value="1:1" name=
              "MultiLocationPicker_checkedNodes.Index" class="t-input" /><input type=
              "checkbox" value="False" name=
              "MultiLocationPicker_checkedNodes[1:1].Checked" class=
              "t-input" /></span><span class="t-in">USA</span><input type="hidden" value=
              "a5261a17-9696-471c-a39a-af11b14bd546" name="itemValue" class="t-input" />
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li class="t-item">
        <div class="t-mid">
          <span class="t-checkbox"><input type="hidden" value="2" name=
          "MultiLocationPicker_checkedNodes.Index" class="t-input" /><input type=
          "checkbox" value="False" name="MultiLocationPicker_checkedNodes[2].Checked"
          class="t-input" /></span><span class="t-in">Africa</span><input type="hidden"
          value="Africa" name="itemValue" class="t-input" />
        </div>

        <ul class="t-group">
          <li class="t-item">
            <div class="t-top">
              <span class="t-checkbox"><input type="hidden" value="2:0" name=
              "MultiLocationPicker_checkedNodes.Index" class="t-input" /><input type=
              "checkbox" value="False" name=
              "MultiLocationPicker_checkedNodes[2:0].Checked" class=
              "t-input" /></span><span class="t-in">Africa</span><input type="hidden"
              value="5c2389eb-365e-42bb-9b1a-8db36f87b4af" name="itemValue" class=
              "t-input" />
            </div>
          </li>

          <li class="t-item t-last">
            <div class="t-bot">
              <span class="t-checkbox"><input type="hidden" value="2:1" name=
              "MultiLocationPicker_checkedNodes.Index" class="t-input" /><input type=
              "checkbox" value="True" name=
              "MultiLocationPicker_checkedNodes[2:1].Checked" class="t-input" checked=
              "checked" /><input type="hidden" value="Headquarters1" name=
              "MultiLocationPicker_checkedNodes[2:1].Text" class="t-input" /><input type=
              "hidden" value="ac171662-3eca-411f-a623-a3cb1a69238e" name=
              "MultiLocationPicker_checkedNodes[2:1].Value" class=
              "t-input" /></span><span class="t-in">Headquarters1</span><input type=
              "hidden" value="ac171662-3eca-411f-a623-a3cb1a69238e" name="itemValue"
              class="t-input" />
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li class="t-item">
        <div class="t-mid">
          <span class="t-checkbox"><input type="hidden" value="3" name=
          "MultiLocationPicker_checkedNodes.Index" class="t-input" /><input type=
          "checkbox" value="False" name="MultiLocationPicker_checkedNodes[3].Checked"
          class="t-input" /></span><span class="t-in">India</span><input type="hidden"
          value="India" name="itemValue" class="t-input" />
        </div>

        <ul class="t-group">
          <li class="t-item">
            <div class="t-top">
              <span class="t-checkbox"><input type="hidden" value="3:0" name=
              "MultiLocationPicker_checkedNodes.Index" class="t-input" /><input type=
              "checkbox" value="False" name=
              "MultiLocationPicker_checkedNodes[3:0].Checked" class=
              "t-input" /></span><span class="t-in">Gurgaon</span><input type="hidden"
              value="d8266db4-e846-4338-906f-e0b84fd9044a" name="itemValue" class=
              "t-input" />
            </div>
          </li>

          <li class="t-item">
            <div class="t-mid">
              <span class="t-checkbox"><input type="hidden" value="3:1" name=
              "MultiLocationPicker_checkedNodes.Index" class="t-input" /><input type=
              "checkbox" value="False" name=
              "MultiLocationPicker_checkedNodes[3:1].Checked" class=
              "t-input" /></span><span class="t-in">MASHALLAAH</span><input type="hidden"
              value="869c083a-a17b-4a7a-a2a9-ef88f972de1b" name="itemValue" class=
              "t-input" />
            </div>
          </li>

          <li class="t-item t-last">
            <div class="t-bot">
              <span class="t-checkbox"><input type="hidden" value="3:2" name=
              "MultiLocationPicker_checkedNodes.Index" class="t-input" /><input type=
              "checkbox" value="False" name=
              "MultiLocationPicker_checkedNodes[3:2].Checked" class=
              "t-input" /></span><span class="t-in">YouThinkSo</span><input type="hidden"
              value="4e33e582-8a54-450a-ad73-70698a578162" name="itemValue" class=
              "t-input" />
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li class="t-item t-last">
        <div class="t-bot">
          <span class="t-checkbox"><input type="hidden" value="4" name=
          "MultiLocationPicker_checkedNodes.Index" class="t-input" /><input type=
          "checkbox" value="False" name="MultiLocationPicker_checkedNodes[4].Checked"
          class="t-input" /></span><span class="t-in">Canada</span><input type="hidden"
          value="Canada" name="itemValue" class="t-input" />
        </div>

        <ul class="t-group">
          <li class="t-item t-last">
            <div class="t-top t-bot">
              <span class="t-checkbox"><input type="hidden" value="4:0" name=
              "MultiLocationPicker_checkedNodes.Index" class="t-input" /><input type=
              "checkbox" value="False" name=
              "MultiLocationPicker_checkedNodes[4:0].Checked" class=
              "t-input" /></span><span class="t-in">West Vancouver</span><input type=
              "hidden" value="b8fd4a6f-bfc7-4c8a-b2ff-cb3c278c7434" name="itemValue"
              class="t-input" />
            </div>
          </li>            
        </ul>            
      </li>             
    </ul>                
  </div>
```

Issues and questions:

```
  On selecting a child node I want the checkbox to get selected/checked in toggle state?
    On selected a parent node I want the checkboxes of the parent and the children to get selected/checked in toggle state.                
    I have tried doing it with the Jquery code above in function              MultiLocationPicker_Selected .                                
Can you tell me how to refactor the code to achieve this functionality.
```

Comment: Please post the relevant **rendered** HTML as the Telerik syntax does not tell us what the resulting HTML is and as such any jQuery would be based on assumption of the DOM structure and most likely be incorrect.

Comment: @Francois - I have posted the relevant HTML can you respond please.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest first giving the parent checkboxes a unique identifier/class and same for its children.

Ill go with

```
Parent Checkbox: <input type='checkbox' class='parent1'/>

  Child1:<input type='checkbox' />
  Child2:<input type='checkbox' />
  Child3:<input type='checkbox' />
  Child4:<input type='checkbox' />
```

Then do something along the lines of

```
if($(".parent1").prop("checked")) {
   $(".parent > input").prop("checked","true");
} else {
   $(".parent > input").prop("checked","false");
}
```

Comment: I cannot give the checkboxes a unique identifier. that is the way the treeview renders the HTML. Can you improve your answer please thanks in advance.